# SFDC - Process Builder - Scheduled Actions based on Date Field? Firing early?

Tags: salesforce, processbuilder

I'm a bit frustrated with a workflow and really hoping someone could help clear things up for me a bit.

The flow and use case:

I have a need to create a workflow where a reminder email is sent to a task owner when their task is expired... essentially the day after the ActivityDate (due date) of the task, since a task doesn't expire until the day after.

To achieve this, I had created a process builder which has a scheduled action to be "1 day after ActivityDate". This seemed fine up until now, but today I'm seeing these flows trigger early.. so I'm not sure if this is a new SFDC bug or just functioning by design.

For example, I've created tasks with an ActivityDate of 7/17/2018. Today is 7/17/2018 PDT. I would expect this flow to send on 7/18/2018 PDT. HOWEVER, this flow kicks off early on 7/17 instead.

Everything I've read seems to indicate that process builder will make this evaluation based on the time-zone of the user that triggered the flow, so I would expect it to evaluate "1 day after" 7/17 to indicate 7/18 00:00:00 PDT.

This does not appear to be the case. Instead it appears to be evaluated based on GMT time. So while it's currently 6:30 PDT (7/17), it's currently 1:30 GMT (7/18)... and must be evaluating to TRUE because of this. This is the only thing I can think of that is causing this flow to kickoff unexpectedly. I have not noticed this issue when testing before, and my assumption is that I have not noticed this strictly because my testing has been done before 5PM PDT.

This issue is further amplified by the fact we have many people around the world working in this one org. So I know I'm going to hit some snags around time-zones.. but I'd much rather have a "past due" task reminder be sent late than early.

I'm not even sure if writing a trigger would get around this issue..

Any information, guidance, or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a trigger/class that creates an activity date when the user is assigned a new task and you could base it on their timezone.

And yes it is an issue with timezone settings.

Any easy fix would be to send it the day after, so some get theirs on time some a day later.